# Select rows based on the values of a specific column (not the first column)

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I would like to read a `file.csv` file and keep the rows (i.e., all the columns) of the file if and only if the sixth column of that file matches values in `user_ids_to_keep.csv`.

The `file.csv` file I would like to read is as following:

```
Year,WeekOfYear,DaysInWeek,USAIsBankHoliday,holidays,**user_id**       
2013,1,5,2,1,1       
2013,1,5,2,1,2       
2013,1,5,2,1,3       
, etc.
```

The `user_ids_to_keep.csv` from which I am getting the matching ids list the ids as following:

```
1    
3    
5    
, etc.
```

The `output.csv` file I would like to create should look like the following:

```
Year,WeekOfYear,DaysInWeek,USAIsBankHoliday,holidays,**user_id**       
2013,1,5,2,1,1       
2013,1,5,2,1,3       
,etc.
```

If the column **user_id** was the first of the file.csv file I believe I could have used the command

```
grep -Fwf
```

but now I am not sure how to get around this.

Comment: how you want to match the sixth column with `user_ids_to_keep.csv` elements ? I mean to say 1st row of sixth column would always match with 1st row of `user_ids_to_keep.csv` or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Show files:

```
head *
```

...which outputs:

```
==> file.csv <==
Year,WeekOfYear,DaysInWeek,USAIsBankHoliday,holidays,**user_id**       
2013,1,5,2,1,1       
2013,1,5,2,1,2       
2013,1,5,2,1,3  

==> user_ids_to_keep.csv <==
1    
3    
5
```

Ugly POSIX code, (can be copied as one-liner):

```
{ read x ; echo $x ; \
  while read x ; \
  do for f in `cat user_ids_to_keep.csv` ; \
     do n=${x#${x%,*},} ; \
         if [ $n = $f ] ; \
         then echo $x ; \
              continue ; \
         fi ; \
     done ; \
  done ; } < file.csv | tee output.csv
```

Displays:

```
Year,WeekOfYear,DaysInWeek,USAIsBankHoliday,holidays,**user_id**
2013,1,5,2,1,1
2013,1,5,2,1,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be written in one line:

```
paste -sd '' user_ids_to_keep.csv | sed 's/[ \t]*//' | xargs -i@ sed -n '/,[@][ \t]*$/p' file.csv
```

Description:

```
paste -sd '' user_ids_to_keep.csv
```

will output the file data in one line without newlines

```
sed 's/[ \t]*//'
```

will delete the all spaces from previous output

```
xargs -i@ sed -n '/,[@][ \t]*$/p' file.csv
```

will use the previous output in variable '@' as a pattern to compare the end of every line from file.csv and print it if pattern matches